# Office 365 Oauth with Nodemailer Can't create new access token

Tags: express, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365, nodemailer

I am trying to use Nodemailer in express server with Oauth from Office 365 but I am getting `Can't create new access token for user` and  `{"code": "EAUTH", "command": "AUTH XOAUTH2"` error. It seems like nodemailer is unable to obtain either the access token and refresh token and the user is not being authenticated to send mails.

```
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.office365.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    tls: {
      ciphers: "SSLv3"
    },
    requireTLS: true,
    auth: {
      type: "OAuth2",
      user: process.env.SENDER_EMAIL,
      clientId: "CLIENT_ID",
      clientSecret: "CLEINT_SECRET",
      accessUrl: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/SOMETHING_SECRET_HERE/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
      // pass: process.env.SENDER_PASSWORD
    }
  });
```

[image]

I am not familiar with OAuth 2.0 with Office 365 to begin with so there could be some configurations error etc. The nodemailer works fine if I use my account credentials though. Can someone please suggest me something to try out or let me know if my config is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> **Please note that, **[`accessUrl`](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/oauth2/#oauth-3lo)** is an endpoint for requesting new access token.**

As you have passed Authorization endpoint, please try changing it to **OAuth 2.0 token endpoint (v2)**.

You can find this **endpoint value** in the Portal like below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> Your App*

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can make use of Microsoft Graph API to send the mails like below:

Make sure to have **`Mail.Send`** permission consented before using the below query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail

{
"message": {
"subject": "Regarding leave approval",
"body": {
"contentType": "Text",
"content": "Please approve my leave request."
},

"toRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"address": "XXXXX"
}
}
],

"ccRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"address": "XXXXX"
}
}
]
},
"saveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**The mail was successfully triggered like below:**

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** the below links:

[Send mail - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Modern Oauth2 authentication for sending mails using Nodemailer nodejs by Sivaprakash-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58322118/modern-oauth2-authentication-for-sending-mails-using-nodemailer-nodejs/58428032#58428032)